# webRTC can't connect to someone on different network

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

So I have a little problem with webRTC.

I have managed to succesfuly establish video communication browser to browser on one computer, and to different computer on the same network using firefox nightly, but I have problem If I try to connect to someone who is on a different network.

I believe this is a problem with Ice servers: This is what I have so far

```
if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == "firefox") {
    var servers = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:23.21.150.121"}]};
} else {
    var servers = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};
}
```

Anyone can help?

By the way, it also has problem when run on chrome, it just randomly doesn't show video (addremotestream is called, but nothing happens).

You can check the source code (ugly) at: http://bndr.me/chat/ 
(the person without querystring is caller, the person with the querystring is the callee)

Comment: Can you please verify that you can use the demo webrtc app with two different computers successfully? https://apprtc.appspot.com I am wondering if you have some firewall/router issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also found this to be a problem.  Actually, I have found it to be the combination of many items, but the network is a big one.  I am sure that others will find this to be a problem as well and it will need to be fixed before most any commercial applications are released.  I think that most don't realize the problem as they are testing on a single PC or perhaps within a LAN and they just don't see the problem. All of my testing has been on Chrome. Here are some details that I have found:

Items that can affect how well the two (or more) endpoints connect.
1.  The network.  I mentions this is a big one.  I have two networks.  AT&T and Comcast cable.  AT&T works well and Comcast poorly.  I will include details of some experience below.
2. Which device connects first assuming different networks, PC types, etc.
3.  The type of PC used.  Windows XP works better than Windows 7. The best one is Ubuntu. In fact I have had no problems at all as long as one of the ends is Ubuntu.
4. Distance.  Generally, the closer the easier to connect.  It makes sense. More specifically, if you are on the same PC or on the same LAN, I have had no problems at all.  If I test from one of my networks to the other (connection goes out to the local WAN and then back to other router/network. I can have some problems.  If I am testing around the World, then I can have more problems.  I frequently test between South Florida in the US to India. That is a problem.

Now let me elaborate on some specifics.  First, let me elaborate on the India problem and some specifics.  If I use Comcast on the Florida end and India end uses their network, I can connect some of the time as long as I connect first and they connect second.  If I switch to ATT, most of the time it will connect either way.  If India uses a Ubuntu PC, then we can always connect no matter what my PC is or what network I use.  Very Strange.  All of our testing is on Chrome and uses the Google STUN server arrangement.

Here is a very specific test I did using a Windows 7 PC (actually two of them although the results were identical) and the Comcast and ATT networks.  I started with Windows 7 and Comcast connecting first; then XP and ATT connected.  No problem. Repeated and again no problem.  I then did it in reverse--starting with the XP and ATT and then connecting the Windows 7 (Comcast). Would not connect. I did a refresh on the Windows 7. No better. Repeated. No connection.  I then went to the XP and tried to refresh. Connected right up.  I ran this same exact sequence two more time with the exact same result.  At least it was consistent.

I then reversed the network connections on the two computers.  I got the exact same result, but just reversed.  That is if the PC that had the ATT connection was the second one to connect, it worked and worked consistently every time. If Comcast was the second connection, it never connected.

My conclusion: The Comcast network or perhaps the router I was using with it was not allowing the connection. I checked everything with no success.  I then used a Ubuntu PC.  The network problem suddenly got solved.  It is not a network issue.

This is a real problem and needs to be fixed before any commercial development is released.  The problem seems to related to a mix of things that I don't understand.  Any help is appreciated.
Fred Clark

Answer (score 0):

Bjoern,  I have used the appspot application with similar results.  I have used three or four different PC's from this location and several from India.  If you want to test the server that I am usually using you can go to www.connectuscom.com/wordpress/.  On the right side of the page is a column of demo applications.  This is the first one in the list.  Fred

Comment: Yes, it is the first one in the list. The one that says Basic Video Meeting.

Answer (score 0):

One other item that I should have included in the beginning.  I'm not sure this is a connection problem at all, but maybe something after the connection.  We play an audio alert when a remote party joins the conference.  That alert play whether we get a connection or not (let me say that it used to do that).  We have made some recent changes in our code and now it doesn't do that.  We also capture diagnostics.  I was going to show that happening and send the diagnostics, but I see that it is no longer doing that.  I am going to show you the diagnostics anyway.  Before I do that you mentioned testing on AppSpot.  I mentioned that I have done that with the same results.  I also test yesterday on Bistri.com with the same results.

This test is using two Windows 7 PCs setting side by side, but connected to two different networks. I started with the ATT network and then connected the Comcast network.  No connection.  I then did a refresh from the ATT computer and got connected the first time.  This is a consistent result.  I am not going to display the diagnostics from the Comcast PC.

For some reason I can't send the diagnostics, but I have them in a notepad file if you want them.  My email is Fred.Clark@VideoConfTech.com.